# No error for instance variable not set in constructor: bug?

Tags: flowtype

[Try Flow example](https://flowtype.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVBjGBDAzrsABQFMAnXOAOzAG9UwxLsBbYgLjFwBdSBLSgOaoAvuigBXShi68qYAcS4A5FsQAUABw4lyVAJQdufQbXphSi8aWoaAdE1YigA).

Does it make sense that there's no type error here?

```
/* @flow */

class Person {
  name: string
}

function getName(p: Person): string {
  return p.name
}
```

It seems to me like either `Person` needs to be considered as an abstract class, or I should get an error indicating that I need to initialize the `name` variable.

Edit: I guess this must be expected, considering [this file](https://github.com/facebook/flow/blob/master/tests/class_fields/base_class.js) in flow's test suit, where they specifically mention uninitialized-but-typed fields. But can anyone explain why flow would think that's ok?

Comment: See also https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/802

Comment: Ah, good catch! Bummer that it's such an old issue.